# Convert <img src="phone.png"> to Base64 <img src="data:img/png;base64,...."> by compiling the app, to make the image load instantly with the app

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, base64, angular-cli

*This is a unique question:* **I don't want to use browser javascript to solve this, please read on...**

---

#### **I want to convert `<img src="...">` to Base64 img tag by compiling the app (`ng build` or `ng serve`), to make the image load instantly - without further downloads other than the app itself, but also to make the image dynamicly changable while developing the app.**

For example, here's a component - `home.component.html`:

**code before compiling (notice the base64 directive, its just an idea though):**

`<img src="assets/images/phone.png" base64>`

**code wanted after compiling:**

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0......rest-of-base-64-goes-here">`

---

**Important:** This should happen **without** running a front-end javascript operation by the user, or by calling the image file. (by means, the file `phone.png` will not even exist when compiling)

I still want to edit the local image `phone.png` while developing.

I know I can convert the file to base64 manually and update it in my component, but that's exactly what I don't want to do - I want it to happen automatically to save time.

That means **the image will sit in the component itself**, in one of the **.js** files that has been compiled, and therefore will load instantly with the app.

---

#### Idea: It would be nice and easy to have a directive that would take care of that.

something like `<img src="phone.png base64>`**

I assume it can be done using node/webpack in some way, but I have not idea how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: @SmokeyDawson nothing related to angular components there

Comment: angular is javascript, your best bet is to create a `convertToBase64()` method that follows one of the answers in the linked question and then in your html do this `[src]="convertToBase64('assets/images/home/home-phone.png')"`

Comment: @SmokeyDawson I understand your answer, however I don't want to compile it on the user's front end. I want it to compile when I run `ng build` and move into my JS chunk file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `readAsDataUrl()`

```
function getBase64(event) {
   let me = this;
   let file = event.target.files[0];
   let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     //me.modelvalue = reader.result;
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
```

Hope can help you..

Comment: Thank you for your time @Shah . How do I make the file compile to base64 when running `ng build`?